# Using bind inside a function that passes (as its argument) a dynamic value to be used by the bind method itself

Tags: javascript, bind

I'm practising with the apply, call and bind methods and I'm trying to use bind in the following context:

```
const chardonnay = {
  type: "still white",
  grape: "chardonnay",
  region: "France",
  description: function () {
    return `This is a ${this.type} wine made of 100% ${this.grape} grapes from ${this.region}.`;
  },
};

const malbec = {
  type: "still red",
  grape: "malbec",
  region: "Argentina",
};

const describeWine = (wine) => {
  return chardonnay.description.bind(wine);
};

console.log(describeWine(malbec));
```

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is that I can pass a dynamic value to be used by bind later on so that I store the bind functionality on another function which parameter will be the argument for the bind function method.

I'm sorry but this is the best I can explain it.

Can someone explain why this approach is not giving me the desired results and what would be the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: Why not simply `const describeWine = chardonnay.description` ?

Comment: If you really need `bind`, the syntax is `.bind(this, wine)`

Comment: @Calculuswhiz that's exactly what i was missing... the thing is, does this way to use bind make any sense? Or i'm just doing something silly? What do you think?

Comment: @JeremyThille the thing is that I want to apply the functionality of chardonnay.description to any wine (object) that gets passed as an argument of the describeWine function. Does it make any sense what I'm trying to accomplish? What do you think?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I completely agree but I'm just trying to practice some use cases with the apply, bind and call methods. Anyway thanks for suggesting the use of classes

Comment: @Calculuswhiz ok I completely get what you mean, I'll follow your advice and won't do it this way. I guess I just have to keep on practicing to understand how the this scope changes with each of them. It just takes some time to get used to. Thanks for sharing your insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call the bind's returned function like this :

```js
const chardonnay = {
  type: "still white",
  grape: "chardonnay",
  region: "France",
  description: function () {
    return `This is a ${this.type} wine made of 100% ${this.grape} grapes from ${this.region}.`;
  },
};

const malbec = {
  type: "still red",
  grape: "malbec",
  region: "Argentina",
};

const describeWine = (wine) => {
  return chardonnay.description.bind(wine)();
};

console.log(describeWine(malbec));
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! What do you think about what I'm trying to accomplish here? Is it a silly use of the bind method or does it make sense to you?

Comment: It makes sense but there is a lot way of doing what you want. You can just pass an object to the function for example